# Updates won't install - software center stuck

Tags: updates

The software center says I have a few updates, but they won't install.
It just says 'installing' forever.  No progress bar moving or anything.

Please advise.

Comment: I think its done now.
It said some index files failed to download, and the old one shave been used instead.
But when I check for updates now it says everything is up to date.
As long as the index files are nt important, I think everything is ok? Thanks

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh After you and guntbert voted to close this question as irreproducible, please read the above comment by the OP (if you haven't read it already) that the question is reproducible and in fact it has a posted answer which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Close the Software Center because it's stuck. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get this error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

run this command to fix it:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If that doesn't work try running `sudo apt-get install -f`(to fix broken packages) and then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again.

If that doesn't work either run the following commands:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates   
sudo rm * # This removes all files from /var/lib/dpkg/updates/.
```

Right after I boot Ubuntu for the first time after installing it, I use the terminal to install all my favorite applications instead of the Software application because if the terminal gets stuck at least it shows an error message.

Comment: also it has to download the updates, it could take a long time f there are a lot of updates.

Comment: Thanks, I did the first update command.
But when that finished, I typed the second upgrade command, and go this error: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run ' sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Comment: I think its done now. It said some index files failed to download, and the old one shave been used instead. But when I check for updates now it says everything is up to date. As long as the index files are nt important, I think everything is ok? Thanks

Comment: That message is a warning, not an error message. I think everything's OK now. If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.